# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for spark-submit

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I built *.jar file for my apache spark scala project using maven. When I try to execute the main class, at some line of the code it provides the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for the class `org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS`.

I run the spark-submit as follows:

```
sudo -u hdfs /usr/bin/spark-submit --class 
org.apache.spark.examples.ml.MyTest spark-examples-*.jar --rank 10 --path 
/home/ubuntu/data
```

It looks like it only cannot find `org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS`. I have the following import statements in the class:

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.ml

import java.util.Date
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.examples.mllib.AbstractParams
import org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext}
import scopt.OptionParser
```

How to solve this issue?

**UPDATE 1:**

I added `maven-assebly` plugin to `pom.xml` and also `assembly.xml` into the folder `resources`. Then I successfully made `mvn package`, but again the same problem.

**UPDATE 2:**

```
jar -tvf spark-examples-1.5.3-SNAPSHOT-hadoop2.2.0.jar | grep "ALS"

  2678 Mon May 23 13:11:44 CEST 2016 org/apache/spark/examples/ml/recommendation/MyFunc$ALSParams.class
```

Answer (score 0):

First find out reason for failure. 
1) Is class missing ? 
2) or It is initialization problem.

 
To find out whether class is available run command `jar -tvf <.jar> | grep "class name"` by this way you can find out whether class file is present or not or its initialization issue.

Comment: Thanks. I runned `jar -tvf <.jar> | grep "ALS"` from the terminal (the directory where `jar` file is located). It says `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'`

Comment: jar -tvf  <jar file name which should contain ALS class>

Comment: jar -tvf com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar | grep "ParserBase"
 16912 Mon Oct 08 19:43:02 IST 2012 com/fasterxml/jackson/core/base/ParserBase.class
L-IDC2CUDKQ2-M:Downloads msing20$

Comment: Please see my update 2. It looks like ALS is not included into jar. Only ALSParams. What would you recommend then? Should I use maven deploy? (I would prefer to avoid this option for my current tests).